# String Pattern (**/*) does not work on Windows

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, path

When I do `path.join(__dirname, 'public', '**/*.png')` in Linux it runs perfectly fine, but on windows system it throws a error of glob not found

```
ERROR in unable to locate 'D:\Projects\<project_name>\public\**\*.png' glob
```

Answer (score 0):

glob only works with paths on the server's file system, I'm assuming there is no folder called <project_name>\public\ on your server.

Or use an absolute path:

$images = glob('D:\Projects<project_name>\public'$item['id'].'.{.png}', GLOB_BRACE);

Comment: <project_name> is an example like `D:\Projects\my-node-app\public\**\*.png`